# Multiple boxplots from a list of dataframes R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to make a boxplot of each column except for the first 2. However, they will be used for other purposes.

My df below

```
df <- structure(list(SAMPLE_NO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("137380", 
"137796", "137926", "138180", "138217", "138233", "138569", "138978", 
"139128", "139137"), class = "factor"), Repeat_No = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L
), Fe = c(59.78, 59.59, 59.76, 59.49, 59.72, 59.74, 59.52, 59.85, 
59.73, 59.61, 59.71, 59.76, 59.73, 59.56, 59.82, 59.71, 59.6, 
59.86, 59.78, 59.84, 59.49, 59.75, 59.71, 59.73, 59.51, 59.75, 
59.77, 59.83, 59.55, 59.6, 59.68, 59.57, 59.73, 59.76, 59.58, 
59.48, 59.79, 59.73, 59.64, 59.85, 59.75, 59.68, 59.63, 59.73, 
59.78, 59.59, 59.69, 59.79, 59.69, 59.7), SiO2 = c(5.1, 5.14, 
5.11, 5.14, 5.14, 5.12, 5.13, 5.11, 5.09, 5.09, 5.12, 5.15, 5.13, 
5.11, 5.14, 5.11, 5.1, 5.12, 5.1, 5.11, 5.12, 5.15, 5.16, 5.11, 
5.12, 5.17, 5.11, 5.15, 5.12, 5.15, 5.12, 5.17, 5.12, 5.13, 5.12, 
5.12, 5.1, 5.1, 5.14, 5.1, 5.11, 5.1, 5.14, 5.15, 5.07, 5.1, 
5.1, 5.11, 5.12, 5.11), Al2O3 = c(2.08, 2.09, 2.09, 2.1, 2.06, 
2.08, 2.07, 2.09, 2.06, 2.1, 2.09, 2.11, 2.07, 2.07, 2.09, 2.06, 
2.07, 2.09, 2.1, 2.08, 2.08, 2.09, 2.08, 2.07, 2.07, 2.07, 2.1, 
2.07, 2.07, 2.1, 2.07, 2.11, 2.09, 2.07, 2.11, 2.06, 2.09, 2.09, 
2.08, 2.05, 2.08, 2.07, 2.08, 2.1, 2.08, 2.08, 2.1, 2.05, 2.07, 
2.08), TiO2 = c(0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame")
```

I also have a list of dataframes with some values that I want to use to draw lines on each boxplots, namely the mean and sd.

my list of dataframes

```
df2 <-list(Fe = structure(c(59.6938, 0.103625897007515), .Dim = 1:2, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("hm", "hsd"))), SiO2 = structure(c(5.121, 0.0214998813475606
), .Dim = 1:2, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("hm", "hsd"))), Al2O3 = structure(c(2.0812, 
0.015069905136275), .Dim = 1:2, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("hm", 
"hsd"))), TiO2 = structure(c(0.14, 0), .Dim = 1:2, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("hm", "hsd"))))
```

and my code to make the box plots

```
plotorder <- sort(unique(df2$SAMPLE_NO))

imap(df2, ~{
  ggplot(df, outlier.shape = NA, 
         mapping = aes(x = SAMPLE_NO, y = .data[[.y]], color = SAMPLE_NO)) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar')+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = as.numeric(c(min(.y),max(.y))))+
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'blue', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1]]))) + #mean
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1]]) #mean 
                             - (as.numeric(.x[[2]])) * 3)) + # subtract SD
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[2]]) #mean value 
                             + (as.numeric(.x[[2]])) * 3)) + # Add SD
    ggtitle(paste0(.y, " Homogeniety Box Plot")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    xlab(label = "Sample No") +
    ylab(paste0(.y, ' values %'))
}) -> list_plot_box
list_plot_box

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

which produces produces a boxplot for three of the columns but not the first one and the lines are located in the wrong lcoation for each chart.  things are being mapped incorrectly to get the values but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `c(min(.y), max(.y))` is incorrect as the `.y` refers to the names of the 'df2' i.e. "Fe", ...

```
imap(df2, ~{
  ggplot(df, outlier.shape = NA, 
         mapping = aes(x = SAMPLE_NO, y = .data[[.y]], color = SAMPLE_NO)) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar')+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = as.numeric(c(min(df[[.y]]),max(df[[.y]]))))+
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'blue', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1]]))) + #mean
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1]]) #mean 
                             - (as.numeric(.x[[2]])) * 3)) + # subtract SD
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1]]) #mean value 
                             + (as.numeric(.x[[2]])) * 3)) + # Add SD
    ggtitle(paste0(.y, " Homogeniety Box Plot")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    xlab(label = "Sample No") +
    ylab(paste0(.y, ' values %'))
}) -> list_plot_box
```

-checking the output of first `list` element

```
> list_plot_box[[1]]
```

[image]

---

Regarding the lines not showed, it is just that the difference in the `ylimit` compared to the first one is so small that it was  not showed.  If we change by removing the `* 3`, it would show

```
imap(df2, ~{
  ggplot(df, outlier.shape = NA, 
         mapping = aes(x = SAMPLE_NO, y = .data[[.y]], color = SAMPLE_NO)) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar')+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = as.numeric(c(min(df[[.y]]),max(df[[.y]]))))+
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'blue', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1]]))) + #mean
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1]]) #mean 
                             - (as.numeric(.x[[2]])) )) + # subtract SD
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1]]) #mean value 
                             + (as.numeric(.x[[2]])) )) + # Add SD
    ggtitle(paste0(.y, " Homogeniety Box Plot")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    xlab(label = "Sample No") +
    ylab(paste0(.y, ' values %'))
}) -> list_plot_box
```

-checking

```
list_plot_box[[1]]
```

[image]

---

We can get all the plots in single page

```
library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(plotlist = list_plot_box, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

Comment: that fixes the scale problem but is not drawing all my lines that I want to display

Comment: thanks for the additional tip with putting all the plots on a single page but my end product will have over 30 box plots so will be too crowded.

Comment: @Spooked you may have to adjust those values instead

Comment: @Spooked I think the main issue is that your the ylimit is so close to the one you already drawn i.e. `as.numeric(df2[[1]][[1]]) -(as.numeric(df2[[1]][[2]]) * 3)
[1] 59.38292`  If you remove the `* 3`, it will be noticeable as the difference is large

Comment: i.e. `as.numeric(df2[[1]][[1]])
[1] 59.6938` is not that much different from 59.38 in the scale you showed for y limit

Comment: thanks for point out my error.  I have made a few additional amendments to my code to make it get what I want and make it easier read

Answer (score 0):

In the end I created a dataframe with the plotting parameters I needed and then mapped them GGPLot to make each chart

```
df2 <- $Fe
          hm       hsd     hmin     hmax
[1,] 59.6938 0.1036259 59.38292 60.00468

$SiO2
        hm        hsd   hmin   hmax
[1,] 5.121 0.02149988 5.0565 5.1855

$Al2O3
         hm        hsd    hmin    hmax
[1,] 2.0812 0.01506991 2.03599 2.12641

$TiO2
       hm hsd hmin hmax
[1,] 0.14   0 0.14 0.14
```

then changed my main bit of code as

```
imap(df2, ~{
  ggplot(df, outlier.shape = NA, 
         mapping = aes(x = SAMPLE_NO, y = .data[[.y]], color = SAMPLE_NO)) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar')+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = as.numeric(c(.x[3],.x[4])))+
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'blue', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1]]))) + #mean
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = .x[4] )) + # subtract SD
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = .x[3] )) + # Add SD
    ggtitle(paste0(.y, " Homogeniety Box Plot")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    xlab(label = "Sample No") +
    ylab(paste0(.y, ' values %'))
}) -> list_plot_box

list_plot_box[[1]]
```

[image]